# execute aync methods in order

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have:

```
public myclass
{
public async Task method1();
public async Task method2();
public async Task method3();
}
```

I implement a function which should execute on myclass object these  3 mthods one after another. I am not sure which way is better (performance/correctness):
1)

```
public async Task mymethod(myclass obj)
{
await obj.method1();
await obj.method2();
await obj.method3();
}
myclass myobj = new myclass();
await myobj.method(myobj);
```

2)

```
public Task mymethod(myclass obj)
{
obj.method1();
obj.method2();
obj.method3();
}
myclass myobj = new myclass();
await myobj.method(myobj);
```

Comment: first one is probably better because it compiles.

Comment: @Selman22 Could've fooled me.

Comment: @AntP: the second example is missing both a semicolon and a return statement.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Yes, and the first is not in a much better state.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: Or an `async` modifier...

Comment: @JonSkeet: he only needs `async` if he wants to use an `await` statement. There's no `await` statement in the `mymethod()` method.

Comment: @AntP: yes, true...he's left the semicolon out of the first as well. But that seems like an easier-to-notice, easier-to-fix omission. :)

Comment: @PeterDuniho: No, but it would still be *valid* code if it were an `async` method; no return statement is *needed*. It wouldn't be a good idea, but it wouldn't be an error. (There'd be a warning, mind you.)

Comment: @JonSkeet: ah, I see what you mean...yes, it's either/or. He could add `async` instead of a return statement. True!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the first example is correct.

Even if you fixed the second example so that it returned a `Task` object, you still would have the problem that each individual method would be operating concurrently with the other two, which seems to be exactly what you *don't* want. I.e. in the second example, you don't wait for one method to finish before calling the next.

Since you would have to add some kind of waiting to the second example anyway, just to get it to work correctly, you should just go ahead and use the correct, idiomatic `async`/`await` technique seen in your first example.